# How can I embed a printer control code into a crystal report?

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

When you send a crystal report (XI) to a pos receipt printer, Is there a way so that we can pass along a printer control code such as partial cut?  We using VB6

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refer to:

[How do I send control characters to a Windows printer in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266652/how-do-i-send-control-characters-to-a-windows-printer-in-crystal-reports)

If your devices uses some kind of sequence that uses 'standard' text and not special codes like an escape then you might be able to embed the text as the last element on your page as a text block in a printer resident font.  We've done this in the past and it's work quite well.